# C++ WIN32 WM_KEYDOWN doesn't respond

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, messagebox, onkeydown

In case **WM_KEYDOWN** has a `messagebox()` in order to understand the functionality of this case.

somebody can help me why this case didn't response?

I'm trying to do debugging this while i insert some letter from keyboard and debugger not coming to **WM_KEYDOWN** case.

Thanks to all!

this is my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
  switch( msg )
  {
  case WM_CREATE:
    break;
  case WM_COMMAND:
    break;
  case WM_KEYDOWN:
    MessageBox(NULL,L"test",L"Information",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    break;
  case WM_DESTROY:
    // DESTROY WINDOW
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
  }
  return  0;
}
```

Comment: You don't really return anything in that case. I know that `MessageBox` returns an `int`, so you need to take that into account as well.

Comment: The WM_KEYDOWN is probably going to another window.  Are you pressing a key in a text box?  If so the WM_KEYDOWN is going to the text box's WndProc.  You can also try using Spy++ and watch where the messages are sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox()` displays a popup dialog and then runs its own modal message loop to service messages for that dialog until it closes.  While the dialog is active, your keystrokes are going to that dialog and not to the window that your `WndProc()` belongs to.  That is why you are not getting more `WM_KEYDOWN` messages.  You should not be using `MessageBox()` as a debugging tool for UI messages, because it changes the flow of UI messages.  Use `OutputDebugString()` instead.  That way, your debugger (or an external viewer like SysInternals DebugView) can display your debug messages without affecting your UI's behavior.